# Recovering files from a deceased person's laptop with Windows Password and Drive Encryption?

Tags: windows-7

I have a deceased person's laptop, from which I would like to recover data.

It has a McAfee Drive Encryption password and a Windows Password (Windows 7 Professional).

None of the family members know it's Windows password, but we know the drive encryption password.

We would like to recover his (the deceased person's) files from it. Is there a way this can be done?

I tried using System Rescue CD and this tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-your-forgotten-windows-password-with-the-linux-system-rescue-cd/

But I was not able to get into the Windows folder (probably because of drive encryption?)

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Perhaps they did not want anyone to have access to their files....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for your loss.  Unfortunately your loss most likely includes this persons data.

McAfee Drive Encryption provides full disk encryption, and it will be encrypted with 128 bit encryption - Assuming Intel (who own the McAfee brand) have done it right - and they most likely have - the only way to recover the data would be to find the password or brute-force it.   Brute Forcing it would rely on him having a weak password, and you having a lot of luck, a powerful computer and appropriate software - [software which most likely does not come cheap](https://www.passware.com/kit-forensic-sdk/filetypes/).